# Считывать сигнал с изображения

Tags: видео

Всем доброго!
Подскажите в каком направлении двигаться, с чего начать, можно ли вообще это реализовать?
**Нужно следующие:** Из прямой трансляции считывать определенный видеоролик, после чего подавать сигнал для замещения прямой трансляции на плейлист с роликами. Также продолжать анализировать прямую трансляцию для считывания того же самого видео ролика, чтобы завершить замещение прямой трансляции плейлистами, то есть вернуть в исходное состояние.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Из какой трансляции в каком формате? Какой сигнал какого формата куда подавать? Что подразумевается под словом "считывать"?